# Generics, template literal types and union types not working together in PhpStorm

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I apologize for English. I work with a translator.

There is a type of function where I convey 2 string parameters and use generics to declare the return type as template literal type.

The following problem arose when trying to achieve the desired typification. The code is given for example:

```js
function example<T extends string, U extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: U,): `${Uncapitalize<T>}${Capitalize<U>}` {
  return `${arg1[0].toLowerCase()}${arg1.slice(1)}${arg2[0].toUpperCase()}${arg2.slice(1)}`;
}

function example<T extends string, U extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: U,): `${Uncapitalize<T>}${Capitalize<U>}` {
  return `${arg1[0].toLowerCase()}${arg1.slice(1)}${arg2[0].toUpperCase()}${arg2.slice(1)}`;
}

declare const arg11: 'test', arg12: 'example';
const result1 = example(arg11, arg12); // GOOD return type "testExample"

declare const arg21: 'test' | 'testTwo', arg22: 'example';
const result2 = example(arg21, arg22); // BAD return type string

declare const arg31: 'test', arg32: 'example' | 'example2';
const result3 = example(arg31, arg32); // BAD return type string

declare const arg41: 'test' | 'test2', arg42: 'example' | 'example2';
const result4 = example(arg41, arg42); // GOOD return type "testExample" | "testExample2" | "test2Example" | "test2Example2"
```

I attach a screenshot from PhpStorm:

[image]

There is a function that accepts 2 arguments and returns a combined string. Problem with literal types. The typification works well when both union type or when both are not union type. In other cases, the returned type just gives out a string. How to make typification work for all cases?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When I copy and paste that into my IDE I get a *lot* of errors unrelated to what you're asking.  Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] where the only problems present are the ones you're asking about.

Comment: An attempt to just make you code compile yields what seems to be the correct types? https://tsplay.dev/wOr8yW

Comment: I corrected the code for what I proposed 
Alex Wayne and attached a screenshot

It looks like this is only a php storm problem. Apologize

Comment: the code snippet still doesn't compile, I get "TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '`${Uncapitalize<T>}${Capitalize<U>}`'."